# Why image is showing in same place with absolute position and random top, left criteria in HTML img generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting issue with this code

```
    function createSmileys(){
            var i = 1;
            var bL=false;
            while(!bL){
                    createNode();
                    if(i==5){
                            bL=true;
                    }
            i+=1;
            }
    }
    function createNode() {
            var x_axis = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
            var y_axis = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
            var ls = document.getElementById("leftside");
            var x = document.createElement("IMG");
            x.setAttribute(":position","absolute");
            x.setAttribute("float","left");
            x.setAttribute("left",x_axis + "px");
            x.setAttribute("top",y_axis + "px");
            x.setAttribute("src", "smile.png");
            x.setAttribute("width", "100px");
            ls.appendChild(x);
    }
```

Though its creating the smileys but they are all aligned on left top corner.
HTML code is here:

```
            <head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                    <script src="generateImage.js"></script>
                    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
                    <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
                    <div id="leftside" onclick="createSmileys()"><p id="p">Left</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="rightSide"><p id="p">Right</p></div>   
            </body>
```

Please help in this code...

Comment: What is there in your style.css? Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m68q9zoc/

Comment: `top`, `position` etc. are CSS attributes, not HTML ones. `setAttribute` does set HTML attributes, not CSS ones. you need to change your element's `style` poperty (`x.style.top = ...; x.style.float=...`) or to set its `style` attribute with the whole string (`x.setAttribute('style', position:...;'float:...; top:...`)

Comment: Thankyou, I confused the setAttribute with CSS attributes, now I've fixed with what you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your setAttribute(":position");

:position is not any type of attribute.please correct it.